# How can I trust the add-in pro-grammatically using csom instead of pressing "trust it" button?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom

I have created SharePoint app and installed the app in SharePoint site using CSOM(c#).however, here manual intervention is required to trust my add-in by clicking `"Trust it"` button. Now,

How can I trust my add-in programmatically by using CSOM?